# iPad Filemaker Go 12 append PDF issues

Tags: ipad, filemaker

I have a script that exports two layouts to pdf and appends them to an attached email. It works perfect on my Mac, but only shows the last pdf I am trying to append on the ipad.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am currently using a TemporaryPath variable which works fine on the mac. 
Script can be found here http://www.coquet.com.au/wp-content/Filemaker.png

Really need help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The append option is not supported on Go.

Per the [FileMaker 12 Go Development Guide](http://www.filemaker.com/support/product/docs/filemaker-go/fmgo_development.pdf)...

```
Some Save Records as PDF script step options aren’t supported:

- appending records to an existing PDF
- selecting the Acrobat version
- selecting Printing and Editing options on the Security tab
```